# QLabel, removing border and background

Tags: c++, qt

I have several instances of `QLabel` and I want these rendered without border or background colour. I tried the following:

```
plbl = new QLabel();
plbl->setGeometry(210, 0, 26, 16);
plbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
plbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
plbl->setStyleSheet("border: 0px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0%);");
plbl->show();
```

I also tried changing the style sheet parameter to:

```
plbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 0px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0%);}");
```

and:

```
plbl->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
```

None of these work.  I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1, Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 5.2.1 20151129, 32 bit)

I have no choice on the Qt version its part of an SDK for an ACR890 handset.

[Edit]  To fix the alignment, use the Qt specific CSS assignment:

```
     qproperty-alignment: 'AlignVCenter | AlignCenter';
```

The quotes and more importantly the pipe are important.

Removing the borders was solved by giving the QLabel constructor a parent, it wasn't a CSS border that was visible, each label was being rendered as a window without a parent.

Comment: Do you mean a visible border (like a box drawn around it,) or just the margins? QLabel does not have a border. Also, when you say "remove the background color", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @NikosC. What I want is the labels to be rendered with no frame or border or background so they appear just as text on a any background they are added to.

Comment: On any platform I've used `QLabel` behaves exactly the way you require by default.  Are you sure the border/frame are due to the `QLabel` itself rather than the containing widget/layout?

Comment: It could be because the QLabel's are created with just new QLabel() and not associated with any layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `QLabel` to be a window itself, you need to remove the window frame and sets the right attributes to avoid the window manager to paint the background.

For example:

```
    QLabel* plbl = new QLabel("foobar");
    plbl->setGeometry(210, 0, 26, 16);
    plbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    plbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
    plbl->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); // No frame
    plbl->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground); // No background
    plbl->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    plbl->show();
```

The label will appear as just a text on the screen.

If you want to insert your label in another widget, you have to set its parent:

```
QLabel* plbl = new QLabel("foobar", parent);
// plbl->show(); // Useless. Done by the parent
```

The label will be displayed in `parent` without background or frame (by default).